# time varying gain LQR vs fixed gain LQR, in finite horizon and infinite Horizon

Tags: control

Consider the dynamic system
$\dot{x}=Ax+Bu$ and the optimal control formulation of
$J = x^TQx + u^TRu$, with optimal linear feedback $u=Kx$ where $K$ is the gain matrix, and I use $k$ to denote time step from 0 to N.

From one book, I read the Riccati iteration derived from dynamic programming going backward from N to 0 (I use prime to denote matrix transpose below) as

$K(k)=-(B'\Pi(k+1)B+R)^{-1}B'\Pi(k+1)A$ with $k=N-1,N-2, ..., 0$
where
$\Pi(k-1)=Q+A'\Pi(k)A-A'\Pi(k)B(B'\Pi(k)B+R)^{-1}B'\Pi(k)A$ with $k=N-1, N-2, ..., 0$
This is a time varying optimal gain, I guess $K(0)\neq K(k)$?

However, from another book, I read the algebraic Riccati equation using variational method, a matrix P has to be found satisfying
$PA+AP^{'}-PBR^{-1}B^{'}P+Q=0$, then the optimal gain is
$K=-R^{-1}B^{'}P$.

My question is, does this mean for discrete time, the optimal LQR gain should be time varying and for continuous time the optimal LQR gain should be a constant matrix? If so, what is the key insight causing such a difference ?

Answer (score 2):

The [algebraic Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Infinite-horizon,_continuous-time_LQR) is for the infinite horizon LQR. For finite horizon one can use the [Riccati differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Finite-horizon,_continuous-time_LQR)

$$
-\dot{P}(t) = P(t)\,A + A^\top P(t) - P(t)\,B\,R^{-1}B^\top P(t) + Q. \tag{1}
$$

The reason why $(1)$ gives an expression for $-\dot{P}(t)$ is because one has to start the differential equation at the time horizon $T$ with $x(t)^\top P(T)\,x(T)$ the terminal state cost and $(1)$ is solved backwards in time until $t=0$.

Similarly, for discrete time one also has the infinite horizon LQR with an associated [algebraic Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Infinite-horizon,_discrete-time_LQR), and the finite horizon LQR with an associated [Riccati difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Finite-horizon,_discrete-time_LQR).